# How can I vectorize the function besselj(m,x) in Matlab where both m and x are are vectors?

Tags: matlab

I want to speed up the following code by vectorization:

```
b = zeros(3,5);
for m=1:3
    for x=1:5
        b(m,x) = besselj(m,x)
    end
end
```

That is, I want to calculate all values of besselj for m ranging over 1 to 3 and x ranging over 1 to 5.

Here is what I tried:

```
m=1:3;
x=1:5;
b = besselj(m,x)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using besselj
NU and Z must be the same size or one must be a scalar.
```

So is it possible to use vectorization of both variables somehow or am I forced to only vectorize one of them and use a for loop for the other?

Comment: Another approach is `bsxfun` with a custom function: `bsxfun(@(mm,xx) besselj(mm,xx), m(:).', x(:))`. But I doubt that will be faster than `meshgrid`/`ndgrid` or a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively use `meshgrid` to compute all the possible pairing `(m, x)` before vectorizing

```
m = 1:3;
x = 1:5;

[X, M] = meshgrid(x,m);

b = besselj(M, X);
```

Comment: It seems out of the answers so far that this the fastest approach when the vectors for x and m are both large, e.g. m=1:150 and x=1:150. It would be interesting to compare it to a MEX version, maybe that could be faster again.

Comment: Instead of transposing the two arrays, do `[X,M] = meshgrid(x,m);`.

Comment: @sonic: Yes, fewer function calls means faster results. But only for relatively small problems. For millions of elements, you’ll find that the loop version is faster because you avoid creating huge intermediate matrices that you don’t use. A MEX-file will be fastest, because you don’t create the intermediate arrays, and don’t have the repeated MATLAB function calls. However, the differences will all be relatively small because computing the Bessel function is quite expensive. Replace `besselj` with something more trivial, and you’ll find the differences between these approaches much larger.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
x = 1:5
b = zeros(3,length(x));
for m=1:3
    b(m,:) = besselj(m,x);
end
```

So yes, you can only vectorize one of the arguments. But in my experience vectorizing along the "longer" axis is often sufficient.